# How to prevent the last page of an odd number of pages to be printed upside down on letterpaper?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, printer, hp-laserjet, duplex

I have a problem with my HP LaserJet 500. When I print a single page on letterpaper (pre-printed with a logo in the top left) there are no problems, when printing an even amount of pages in duplex, no problems.

However when printing an odd number of pages in duplex, (when the last sheet of paper is only printed on 1 side) the printer rotates the last page 180, placing the text in the bottom right with the logo still in the top left.

I have no idea how to fix this. I am already using "alternate mode for letterpaper" and the page is set to flip on the long side, neither is the option "flip page upward (not sure of name)" enabled.

This is of course not a problem on blank paper because I can just rotate the last page, however it is still annoying.

Do you have any idea to why this is happening?
(I'm printing in word BTW)

Answer (score 0):

Some printers have a setting for something like "odd page duplex", which lets it save time by printing a single (or odd) page in simplex rather than duplex. For plain paper that is fine but for letterhead that causes problems.

See if your printer has that setting. Go through the front panel menu or its web browser interface.